# sql data convert to json

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

[image]

Below is my query result. i want the json out put as :

```
[
 {id:1,
  name:a,
  category : [
               {name:balakrishnan},
               {name:nikhil}
             ]
},
{id:2,
  name:b,
  category : [
               {name:midhun},
               {name:amith}
             ]
}
]
```

**I have done this with async parallel, i just want to know where we can do in another approach  like map functions**

Comment: sql doesn't store data in terms of json, use an ORM to get the data as objects.

Comment: currently in the middle of project cant implement ORM at this stage